# How to isolate specific boolean island given a coordinate on it?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Given a 2d array with Boolean islands where 1 is land and 0 is water. Lets say I want only the island to which I point with a coordinate. How would I transfer it to a new array where everything beyond the borders of that island is water.

Here is a simple example.
I am given this 2d array

```
1 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 0
```

and the coordinate [1][2] (that would be the 2nd column 3rd row)
Then the final result in the new array should be something like

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0
```

The pixels can only be connected either up, down, left or right to each other (no diagonals)

Comment: What you're after is generally called https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

Comment: Look at the "one component at a time"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks for the link. It all just made sense.